# My SVG created with javascript is not shown

Tags: javascript, svg

I try to do [this effect](https://codepen.io/fredbros/pen/vYQVKBj) (forked from [Fabio Ottaviani](https://codepen.io/supah/pen/poxmKPQ)).

But i need to create this SVG with Javascript.

ChatGPT answer seems to be ok.
The SVG is created into the DOM, but it doesn't appear on screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <title>SVG created with JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    // Function to create an SVG element with given attributes
    function createSVGElement(tag, attributes) {
      const element = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", tag);
      for (const key in attributes) {
        element.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]);
      }
      return element;
    }

    // Create the circle with the "displacement" class
    const circleMask = createSVGElement("circle", {
      cx: "200",
      cy: "200",
      r: "100",
      fill: "white",
      class: "displacement",
    });

    // Create the image
    const image = createSVGElement("image", {
      "xlink:href": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1630563451961-ac2ff27616ab?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTF8fGFwcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fHww&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=400&q=60",
      width: "400",
      height: "400",
      mask: "url(#circleMask)",
    });

    // Create the mask and add the circle
    const mask = createSVGElement("mask", { id: "circleMask" });
    mask.appendChild(circleMask);

    // Create the <defs> element and add the mask
    const defs = createSVGElement("defs");
    defs.appendChild(mask);

    // Create the SVG and add the elements above
    const svgElement = createSVGElement("svg", {
      width: "400",
      height: "400",
      version: "1.1",
      xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
    });
    svgElement.appendChild(defs);
    svgElement.appendChild(image);

    // Add SVG to body
    document.body.appendChild(svgElement);
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>;

    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried :

```
image.addEventListener("load", function () {
      svgElement.appendChild(image);
      document.body.appendChild(svgElement);
    });
```

in order to wait for loading image...

I've also tried

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      document.body.appendChild(svgElement);
    });
```

without result :(

The SVG is in the DOM, I can see it in explorer, all seems to be ok, but, svg isn't shown
[explorer capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuDma.png)

And classical mistake `document.createElement` is eliminated.

Any idea ?

Comment: setAttribute can't create an xlink:href attribute, you'd need to call setAttributeNS for that. Or simpler now, just use "href" rather than "xlink:href" then you **can** use setAttribute.

Comment: Note that most ChatGPT solutions contain subtle error such as this. You're better off not using it for programming questions.

Comment: ``document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend" , "YOUR <SVG> STRING" );`` is the shorter (and I'd say easier) alternative chatGPT won't tell you (ps. chatGPT and CoPilot now do about 50% of my **tedious and boring** programming work)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the "xlink" namespace in front of the href attribute on the image (it is deprecated: [xlink:href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href)). And then you should definitely wait for the DOM to load before inserting anything.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <title>SVG created with JavaScript</title>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
      // Function to create an SVG element with given attributes
      function createSVGElement(tag, attributes) {
        const element = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", tag);
        for (const key in attributes) {
          element.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]);
        }
        return element;
      }

      // Create the circle with the "displacement" class
      const circleMask = createSVGElement("circle", {
        cx: "200",
        cy: "200",
        r: "100",
        fill: "white",
        class: "displacement",
      });

      // Create the image
      const image = createSVGElement("image", {
        "href": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1630563451961-ac2ff27616ab?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTF8fGFwcGxlfGVufDB8fDB8fHww&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=400&q=60",
        width: "400",
        height: "400",
        mask: "url(#circleMask)",
      });

      // Create the mask and add the circle
      const mask = createSVGElement("mask", {
        id: "circleMask"
      });
      mask.appendChild(circleMask);

      // Create the <defs> element and add the mask
      const defs = createSVGElement("defs");
      defs.appendChild(mask);

      // Create the SVG and add the elements above
      const svgElement = createSVGElement("svg", {
        width: "400",
        height: "400",
        version: "1.1",
        xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      });
      svgElement.appendChild(defs);
      svgElement.appendChild(image);

      // Add SVG to body
      document.body.appendChild(svgElement);
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```